# Running Cloud Build trigger via GCP Console returns 'build.service_account' field cannot be set for triggered builds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am currently using Cloud Build for my Dataflow Flex template to kick off jobs.
Here's my current command:

```
gcloud beta builds submit --config run.yaml --substitutions _REGION=$REGION \
--substitutions _FMPKEY=$FMPKEY --no-source
```

Currently this is running fine from Cloud Shell.
But now I want the build to be kicked off based on  a trigger..
So I created  a Cloud Build that will trigger running this file based on dropping a  message to a topic:

```
https://github.com/mmistroni/GCP_Experiments/blob/master/dataflow/pipeline/run.yaml
```

However, after publishing a message to the selected topic, all my builds fail with the following error:

```
our build failed to run: generic::invalid_argument:generic::invalid_argument:
 'build.service_account' field cannot be set for triggered builds
```

I cannot see any logs or details, so it's not clear to me what is going on..
I am guessing it has something to do with the last line in my run.yaml?

```
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY

# Use the Compute Engine default service account to launch the job.
serviceAccount: projects/$PROJECT_ID/serviceAccounts/$PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

However I see no option for selecting the service account in cloud build. Do I need to set some permissions in IAM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct with your guess and this is working as intended.

Cloud Build has a default service account to execute builds on your behalf. While GCP allows you to configure user-specific accounts for additional control, it doesn't apply when you're using build triggers. Build triggers only use the default service account to execute builds.

This is documented in GCP [docs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#security_implications_of_build_triggers):

> *Build triggers use Cloud Build service account to execute builds. This could provide elevated build-time permissions to users who use triggers to start a build. Keep the following security implications in mind when using build triggers ...*

Also as part of [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts#limitations):

> *User-specified service accounts only work with manual builds; they don't work with build triggers.*

Therefore, you must pass a config yaml without `serviceAccount` if you plan on using build triggers.

Comment: thanks Dondi. Now that i have removed the last line in my run.yaml, i am getting this error         2021-07-14 07:53:42.037 BST "message": "(bb107d8b1a0d1897): Could not create workflow; user does not have write access to project: datascience-projects Causes: (bb107d8b1a0d12b2): Permission 'dataflow.jobs.create' denied on project: 'datascience-projects'",   So, now  when using gcloud service account it cannot access my project...  what do i need to do next?  rgds

Comment: Hello. sure,. after my post i went to read docs and re-check my IAMs . i forgot to add roles to cloud build. now all good, have also upvoted your answer. many thanks for help

Comment: @user1068378 it appears that you upvoted my comment, and not the answer. Since my answer solved your problem, please close your question by clicking the ▲ or ✔ (or both) beside my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, other

Answer (score 0):

If you have the error

> Your build failed to run: generic::invalid_argument: if
> 'build.service_account' is specified, the build must either (a)
> specify 'build.logs_bucket' (b) use the CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY logging
> option, or (c) use the NONE logging option

It does work now at the time of writing but you need to configure the logging part as is explained over [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts#running_builds_using_build_triggers). So basically adding this option to the `cloudbuild.yaml` file:

```
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

And creating your trigger as such:

```
gcloud alpha builds triggers create webhook \
  --name=your-trigger-name \
  --secret=projects/{project-number}/secrets/{secret-name}/versions/1 \
  --inline-config=cloudbuild.yaml \
  --service-account=projects/{project-id}/serviceAccounts/{sa-name}@{project-id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

But need to make sure that your service account also has Logs Writer (roles/logging.logWriter) role.